# Manage messages in Websphere MQ based on availability of resources

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am checking for resource availability in `onMessage` method. If resources are available process message if not I am calling `setRollbackOnly()` method which makes MDB Listener stopped for defined JMSDestination after maximum number of retries defined. Is there a way to manage this efficiently?

My onMessage looks something like this:

```
if(isSeverAvailable){
    //process message
}else{
    fMessageDrivenCtx.setRollbackOnly();
}
```

Comment: This is really more of a JMS question than an MQ question so I updated the tags. My gut feeling is that you should manage this at the session level because doing it with rollbacks will cause messages to be requeued to the exception or DLQ and cause the MDB to stop. However I don't work with app servers so hopefully someone who does will respond.